# Django models: adding a new field with unique=True and migrate will fail due to entering a same value to existing records

Tags: django, model

I am adding a new field to a model:

```
class Abc(models.Model):
    ...
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

During `Makemigrations` I provided an empty string once for all. And then `Migrate` failed because of duplicate key `Key (slug)=() is duplicated`.

The follows are what I have tried to solve the problem. `makemigrations` were all OK but `migrate` failed due to the same reason.

1) Remove `unique=True` and migration again

2) Remove the slug field and migration again

3) Set `unique=False` and migrate again

The database can not be deleted. I am stuck and left without options. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are having this problem because there are at least two records in the table that have the same slug.

To fix this, you could do the following steps

1. Create a data migration. `./manage.py makemigrations <app_name> --empty`
2. In the migration file, add django migration's `RunPython` operation in the file. An example would be something like the snippet below.

   ```
   from __future__ import unicode_literals

   from django.db import models, migrations
   from django.utils.text import slugify

   def forwards(apps, schema_editor):
       Abc = apps.get_model('app', 'Abc')
       for obj in Abc.objects.all():
           if len(obj.slug) == 0:
               obj.slug = slugify(obj.field1)
               obj.save()

   class Migration(migrations.Migration):

       dependencies = [
           ('app', '0003_Abc'),
       ]

       operations = [
           migrations.RunPython(forwards, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop),
       ]
   ```
3. Add the `unique=True` to the field.
4. Create the migration. `./manage.py makemigrations <app_name>`
5. Migrate your database. `./manage.py migrate <app_name>`

Comment: I finally found another solution: 1). Delete the failed migration file, leaving previous file intact, 2) Remove unique=True 3) Makemigrations and Migrate. It worked. Thanks, Rod.